# pygame installation for ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone suggest me how to install the pygame for use in the construction of the graphics games using the python?

Answer (score 1):

Download the tarball for pygame from here:

- [Debian repository for pygame](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/pygame.html)

(choose [this](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pygame/pygame_1.9.1release+dfsg-8.debian.tar.gz) if you are not sure which one to download)

Extract the tarball using `tar -zxvf filename`. And then `cd` to the extracted directory and run `python setup.py`.

**Source:** [Installation instructions for pygame](http://www.pygame.org/install.html)